# C# Web Api GET POST json as custom string type

Tags: c#, json, string, asp.net-web-api, put

With `Put` and `Get` request I receive empty strings for a field that should contain json string.

For example: 
I Put the following Json:

```
{
  "card": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "xyz": "dby"
  }
}
```

Now if the receiving class has a member of type JObject, then it is mapped correctly

```
public class contact {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public JObject card { get; set; }
}
```

However if I change the type to a custom string type that can receive all JTokens:

```
public class contact {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string name { get; set; }
      public JsonString card { get; set; } //**Changed HERE**//
    }
```

Then, the Put and Get method both show empty strings.

JsonString looks like as follows:

```
public class JsonString
{
        private string _json;

        public JsonString (string json)
        {
            this._json = json;
        }

        public string Value()
        {
            return _json;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _json.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return (obj is JsonString) && this.GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
                return _json;
        }
}
```

The jsonString class more, but probably not needed in this context. Any idea why The put/Get are returning empty strings and how can I fix this?

EDIT:

The Put looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
 [Route("contacts/{contactid}")]
 public HttpResponseMessage update(int id, contact c) {
 contact.update(c);
}
```

Comment: it's not really a response to your problem but if you have time take a look on Newtonsoft.Json it's easy to use and provides you correct serialization and deserialization for objects to json and backwards.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in your `JsonString`?

Answer (score 0):

JObject looks like this:

```
public class JObject : JContainer, IDictionary<string, JToken>, 
ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>, 
IEnumerable, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanging
```

What you've got is just a string, while JObject acts as a key-value datastucture.

You can't just map it like this. 
You might have better luck with dynamic object but still it is not that simple.